# Changing Boot Order - can only access Linux through 'Use a Device' option

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, linux-mint

I have installed Linux Mint on my Windows 10 laptop today.

Linux works fine but the GRUB menu never shows when the computer is booted.

System uses UEFI.

The only way I'm able to access Linux is by turning on the laptop (which automatically boots to Windows), then go to `Settings -> Update & security -> Recovery -> Restart Now (advanced startup) -> Chose a device -> linux option`

Only after doing the above does the GRUB menu seem to show, and I can select linux / windows.

I have tried a number of options including EasyBCD (which doesn't work becuase my laptop uses EFI) to try and get the GRUB menu to show when the laptop first boots.

I think it may be a boot order issue, because Windows Boot Manager is still first, but none of the other options seem to be GRUB related(?), they are:

`1. Windows Boot Manager
2. HDD: WDC + a serial number
3. ATAPI CDROM: + a serial number
4. USB FDD:
5. Network-Boot-IPV4
6. USB HDD:
7. USB CDROM:
8. Network Boot-IPV6`

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get in linux and get boot-repair. Launch it and click on the "recommended repair"

that should fix it!

If not you should disable secure boot in bios cause that thing is locked to boot only windows!